# Does one need to define case $=0$ for an odd extension?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Does one need to define case $=0$ for an odd extension?

In order to transform e.g. the problem of form

$$\begin{cases}
u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0,  & \text{in } \mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty) \\
u(x,0)=g(x),  & \text{on } \mathbb{R} \times \{ t=0 \} \\
u(0,t)=0, & \text{on } \{x=0\} \times (0, \infty)
\end{cases}$$

to

$$\begin{cases}
\bar u_{tt}-\bar u_{xx}=0,  & \text{in } \mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty) \\
\bar{u}(x,0)=\bar{g}(x),  & \text{on } \mathbb{R} \times \{ t=0 \} \\
\end{cases}$$

The reason to believe that yes I need to is that in order for $u(0,t)=0$ to disappear, then one must define that the odd extension $g(x=0)=0$.

So

$$\bar{g}(x)=\begin{cases}
g(x),  & x \leq 0 \\
-g(-x),  & x < 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

does not suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Though you didn't state it, these problems generally assume that $u$ is to be continuous on its boundary. But that requires that $\lim_{t\to 0+} u(x, t) = g(x)$ for all $x$. When $x = 0$, this means $g(0) = 0$.

You don't need to assume that $\bar g(0) = 0$ because we already have $\bar g(0) = g(0) = 0$.

Comment: How does one know that for $x=0$ $g(0)=0$? I don't see that anything has been given about the values $g(x)$ gets?

Comment: That is what I explained in the first paragraph. In a pde, the function $u$ is to be continuous on its boundary, and by the 2nd boundary condition you gave, that requires that $u(0,0) = 0$, but by the first boundary condition $u(0,0) = g(0)$ and therefore the problem only has a solution when $g(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, now I see it.